# Microsoft Graph in a LARAVEL PHP app - oauth2 grant method 'password'

Tags: laravel, api, graph, oauth-2.0, access-token

i'am using a LARAVEL PHP application which is trying to get a token from Microsoft GRAPH API.
Acutally, i can easily get a token by using the an **OAuth2 Authorisation CODE grant method.**

here is the way to do it : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/php.md

But using this method is redirecting the browser to a Microsoft authentication web page, and i don't want this. I would like a transparent method without any browser redirection.

Here are all the Oauth2 grant méthods to get a token :
https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants

So i want to get a token by using "Resource owner credentials grant". Here is my code :

```
    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([    
    'clientId'          => 'b9e6844b-b20c-4eef-bbff-fa052c1c0f94',
    'clientSecret'      => '1A8yUUcMaD5Zdv1dgwqy3SR',
    'redirectUri'       => 'https://my-website-url/oauth',
    'urlAuthorize'    => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'    => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails'    => '',
    'scopes'                  => 'openid email profile' //  Admin restricted scopes : Directory.Read Directory.ReadWrite Groups.Read.All
]);

$accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('password',[
    'username' => 'myaccount@assystem.com',
    'password' => 'xxxxx'
]);
```

But i got the following error :

***(1/1) IdentityProviderException
invalid_grant
in GenericProvider.php (line 217)***

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

After getting an error exception, i know why i got this error :

```
    try {
    // Try to get an access token using the resource owner password credentials grant.
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('password', [
        'username' => 'myapp@assystem.com',
        'password' => 'mypassword'
    ]);
} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {

    // Failed to get the access token
    throw $e;
}
```

'error_description' => 'AADSTS70000: The grant is not supported by this API version ...(Microsoft Graph API)

Comment: I kept the same Graph API version but i changed the grant method to a "client_credential". This is working good :-)